# MongoDB Many to Many with extra attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, database-schema

Since I'm new to MongoDB, I've got a lot of questions regarding schema design. I'd like to transform my relational schema to a MongoDB-Schema for learning reasons and want to profit from the schema as much as possible.

In my normalized relational database, I've got a many-to-many relationship between modules and lecture_types.

- the modules table has just one attribute: name
- the lecture_types table has the attributes: description,
  default_group_size
- the join table does also have an attribute: hours

My basic use cases are: I want to see the lecture types in the context of a module, so that I have the lecture_types immediately available within a module.

But at the same time, I'd like to have a list of all lecture_types in the system. For example, I'd like to implement a drop-down list in the view for creating a new module, showing all available lecture_types.

Since I basically want to access my modules including the lecture types, i thought of a very denormalized schema design for a module document like this:

```
{
  name: "...",
  lecture_types: [
    { 
      hours: 2,
      lecture_type: { description: "...", default_group_size: 50 }
    },
    { 
      hours: 3,
      lecture_type: { description: "...", default_group_size: 20 }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is that a good idea? The description and the default group size rarely changes, however i don't feel comfortable storing the same information again and again and again. I'm also unsure about the deeply nested, "emulated" join table. Do you have any alternatives?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denormalisation is always done to keep the related data on the same location which has its pros and cons. The pros being query speed, cons being large disk space, difficult query updates.

Talking about the schema, it looks fine. Regarding the deeply nested thing, you shouldn't worry, mongoDB works fine in this part.
If you are concern about 'description' which can be too long and stored multiple times in the same document, then you can put all the 'description' on the top level and and have a reference to them. But you have to check your query requirements ( i.e. how you are updating this document )

Also if possible try to use small keys in mongo, because they are replicated in each and every document. In the application layer you can use better names for those small keys.

```
{
  name: "...",
  ref : {
      1 : 'description1',
      2 : 'description2'
  },
  lecture_types: [
    { 
      hours: 2,
      lecture_type: { description: 1, default_group_size: 50 }
    },
    { 
      hours: 3,
      lecture_type: { description: 2, default_group_size: 20 }
    },
    { 
      hours: 2,
      lecture_type: { description: 1, default_group_size: 40 }
    },
    ....
    ....
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how would you solve my second use case: Selecting all available lecture_types?

Comment: Was the selecting, not selecting from the same document ( i.e. for a particular document with some 'name' ) ?

Comment: I basically want to have a list of all lecture_types available in the system, so that I can run something like: db.lectures.find() for a DropDown Menu. So would it maybe be better to reference instead embedd?

Comment: Its the call that you have to take. If the read queries are very high on the 'name' param then I would have preferred to embed rather than have a reference because then for each reference I will then have to make a db call. This won't be space efficient but the query performance will be very good.
And then you can choose to store all the distinct lectures in some different collection.